# How to call fetch API one after another in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, express, fetch

I have two APIs to backend of OAuth :

```
app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google', {
                scope: ['profile']
            })
        )



app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.user.google)

            res.json(req.user.google)
        }
    )
```

**Front End (JSX)**

```
 //All under React class
 getData = () => {
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback',{
       mode: 'no-cors',
       method: 'get'
      })
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(text => console.log(text))
}

 callFirstApi = () => {
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/google',{
       mode: 'no-cors',
       method: 'get'
  })
 .then(this.getData()) 
} 



 render(){
     return(
          <div className = "" >
       <input onClick = { this.callFirstApi }

  type = "submit"
  value = "Register with Google" />
  </div> 
       )
  }
```

***_____________________________________________________________________________***
**Terminal(Console)**

***InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token
    at Strategy.OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError GET /auth/google/callback?oauth_token=81--b09b6480-9faa-45ee-ac78-1934190&oauth_verifier=28583 500 289.147 ms - 1295***

{ id: 'q5iPMrRJab',

token: 'bfc0bb7-f7c5-4ef5-b97c-0b3e77bf550a',

tokenSecret: 'd473705-ddd3-487b-8838-849a476b29ed',

firstName: 'Some name',

lastName: 'some name'

}

***GET /auth/google/callback?oauth_token=81--d2c05-1af2-4dff-b228-98d88f2caddf&oauth_verifier=59719 200 1639.049 ms - 210***

***_____________________________________________________________________________***

Since **/auth/google** does not give any response it triggers its **callback** api that is why I am trying to nest a callback fetch inside an ***auth/google*** to get the data.
But weirldy, in my console I am getting first token error then followed by a user data and it is not passing any data into frontend

How can I achieve this nested fetch api situation and send to react components ?

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried, which didn't return the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570395/2630817, please take a look

Comment: I have added a complete console output